# How to Create ISO Image of installed Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: iso, 16.10

I've recently updated my ubuntu to 16.10 from 16.04 . I've ISO image of Ubuntu 16.04 (ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) but I donot have iso image of Ubuntu 16.10. How can create it so that I can share Ubuntu 16.10 with my friends and also as a backup in case I need to install it again in the future.

Thank You in advance...!!

Comment: Why would you want to share your installation with your friends? That seems quite insecure, and possibly problematic depending on hardware. However, Clonezilla can do what you wish to do- creates an image of your system and data.

Comment: Why not just download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try SystemBack, here are a few links.

https://launchpad.net/systemback

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/

I havn't used it myself but it claims to do exactly what your looking for.

Comment: According to https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback, 16.10 is not stable.